# how to implement app likes 'Lovecall'?

Tags: ios4

I wanna do functionality like 'Lovecall' or iphone homepage, which can redraw icons automatically with animation. Can you give me idea about how to implement?(Demo is the best).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [OpenSpringboard](https://github.com/fieldforceapp/openspringboard)?

Comment: I found a good website for getting good controllers during you dev..,which is http://www.cocoacontrols.com/